# Android DatePicker scrollers visualization problems

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I have a problem with my date-picker in Android and my HTC Sensation XE.
The scrollers appears like this: [image]
This happens only on my HTC Sensation XE. On a Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini there are no problems.

Do you know if there is a problem specific with htc?

My picker code:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ContainerMainLinearLayout"
    style="@style/LoginFormContainer"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ContainerInnerRelativeLayout" >      

    <DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/dp_bestbefore"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:spinnersShown="true"
    android:calendarViewShown="false"
    android:background="@color/BackGray" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

EDIT:
If I am right, the style:

```
    <style name="ThemeWithTitle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ThemeWithTitle.ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ThemeWithTitle.ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bkg_gradient_aqua</item>
    <item name="android:height">40dip</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ThemeWithTitle.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Did you check it on emulator?  Also please show your style

Answer (score 0):

```
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
private fun initialiseDatePicker()
{
    val myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    val date = DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { _, year, monthOfYear, 
         dayOfMonth ->
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear)
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)
        val myFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(myFormat)
        etRegisterDob.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.time))  
    }
    etRegisterDob.setOnClickListener {
        val d = DatePickerDialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog, date, myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
        d.datePicker.maxDate = System.currentTimeMillis()
        d.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent)
        d.show()
    }
}
```

Comment: a little explaination would be nice